# Get rows from google sheet where column value greater than X (from python api)?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to use the python API to get rows from google sheet where column value greater than X?

Eg. I have a google form that links to a sheet. When a response is added to the sheet, I have appscript code that adds a unix millisecond timestamp to the row. So the sheet looks like...

```
<default form response metadata headers>...<form response headers>...MSTIMESTAMP
<values>...1234567
<values>...1234568
.
.
.
```

I would like to access this sheet from the google python API client and get only values that I have not brought down for processing yet (ie. the values who's mstimestamp is greater than the timestamp value I have stored on the client side). Eg. keep the most recently seen timestamp in a file on the API client side and use it to do some hypothetical snippet like...

```py
latest_ts = get_from_file(latest_timestamp.log)

service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().getBySomeQueryFunction(spreadsheetId=MY_SPREADSHEET_ID
                                               where=f"where MSTIMESTAMP_COLUMN > {latest}").execute()
```

(BTW, the reason I want to use a generated timestamp rather then saving, say, the row number, is because it is not a *guarantee* that rows may not be deleted later in a random fashion (eg. if form responses that make it to the sheet are invalid for some reason)).

Is anything like this possible? Any alternatives to this (basically **trying to avoid bringing down the entire sheet to the client side for processing**)? Saw the sheet's [`getDataByFilter()`](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html#getByDataFilter) docs, but the filter params did not *seem* to be relevant here.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? You want to retrieve the values of searched rows? Or you want to retrieve the searched row numbers?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to retrieve all row's values of the sheet that have the `mstimestamp` column value (my custom millisecond timestamp) greater than some value X.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Eg. I have a google form that links to a sheet. When a response is added to the sheet, I have appscript code that adds a unix millisecond timestamp to the row. So the sheet looks like...`. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: @Tanaike Not much to add on that. Just assume that somehow a millisecond timestamp value get appended to a row when it is entered into the sheet. That timestamp is what I want to query on from the api client in order to only get row values that have not been processed by the client yet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your Google Spreadsheet from `the sheet looks like...`. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and the sample output values you expect? By this, I would like to confirm your goal.

Comment: I don't think you can make this kind of filter on the request. The filtering process should happen after you've retrieved the data from the API. Is there a reason you cannot do this?

Comment: @lamblichus I am trying to avoid bringing down too much data to the client side (especially, since most of the data brought down at any given time will not be useful anyway since only interested in the incrementally added new rows (everything else from past scheduled pulls would need to be filtered out each time)).

Comment: You could use [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to get filtered data, but this would require making the spreadsheet public. Would that be appropriate? Another option would be filtering the data on the spreadsheet itself, by some combination of [Filter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters) and formulas, or what have you. What do you think of these options?

Answer (score 0):

Does your sheet has some header to recognize a column from another?
If you do have some header, and one column is called "timestamp", you could use the [library Sheetfu](https://github.com/socialpoint-labs/sheetfu) and its table module. This is how it would work:

```
from sheetfu import Table

spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp('path/to/secret.json').open_by_id('<insert spreadsheet id here>')
data_range = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('whatever').get_data_range()

table = Table(data_range)

items_to_process = []
for item in table:
    if item.get_field_value('timestamp') >= 'your timestamp threshold':
        items_to_process.append(item)
```

The `items_to_process` list will contain all the rows you want, and you can access any of the row value using the following:

```
my_value = item.get_field_value("my_field")
```

This snippet will work if your header is on the first page. If it is not, you can refer to Sheetfu docs to figure out how to do it.

Comment: That is currently what I do (using the google API client), but what I am trying to do is *not have to bring down all the data the the local machine* for filtering (unless sheetfu is using some kind of lazy evaluation process to get data here, but that does not look like the case in the example).